# change contents of shallow copied array of strings in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, shallow-copy

Suppose I create the following arrays in ruby:

```
a = ["apple", "cherry"]
b = a.dup
```

Here, b is a shallow copy of a.  So if I do:

```
a.each{|fruit| fruit << " pie"}
```

I get both a and b equal to ["apple pie", "cherry pie"].  No problem there.  But suppose I change one element of b:

```
b[1] = "blueberry"
```

and issue the same "each" command.  Now b is ["apple pie", "blueberry"], because a[0] and b[0] are the same strings, but a[1] and b[1] are different strings.  I could run the command on both a and b, but then b is ["apple pie pie", "blueberry pie"], because I have run the append operation on the same string twice.

Is there a way to modify *in place* all the strings of a and b, without duplicates.  In this simple example, I could test for the substring " pie", but this wouldn't work for other types of changes (such as deleting the first character).

I tried creating a set containing all the strings, so that each would be unique; but it seems the set creation copies the strings, so they cannot be modified in place.  Is there a way to test if two strings are the same in memory?  I have googled for that, but found nothing.

The application of this is that I have big arrays of strings, which I "dup" to create a history of them.  Now I want to apply a change to the entire history, without double applying (or triple, etc) the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your use case; I suspect you're making things more complicated than they need to be.

*Is there a way to test if two strings are the same in memory?*

`Object#object_id` is what you're looking for.

*Is there a way to modify in place all the strings of a and b, without duplicates?*

You could keep a set of not all the `object_id`s, similar to what you were already trying.  You can retrieve the string with `ObjectSpace#_id2ref`.  Something like this:

```
require 'set'

set = Set.new
a = ["apple", "cherry"]
b = a.dup
b[1] = "blueberry"

# Collect unique string objects
a.each{|s| set << s.object_id}
b.each{|s| set << s.object_id}

# Make pie with each unique string object
set.each{|id| ObjectSpace._id2ref(id) << " pie"}

a
# => ["apple pie", "cherry pie"]
b
# => ["apple pie", "blueberry pie"]
```

That seems a bit crazy to me, though.  Again, I think there's probably a better way to do what you're trying to do, but it's hard to tell based on the information provided.

Comment: As for use case: I have an array of strings as my main data structure.  As time goes on, I make changes to the array of strings.   I want to store a history of those changes.  To do this, I use 'dup' to make new arrays which hold the same strings.  Then when I change a string, I change only that string.  This saves on memory, because I don't have to store all those duplicate strings.

Comment: Cool, happy to help.  I'm still having trouble imagining wanting something like that, but no worries.  If it works for what you need, great.  I guess the main thing that confuses me is creating a shallow copy as history, then rewriting history when you change shared strings.  Like broken copy-on-write.  But it sounds like you understand the implications of what you're doing and that it works for you, so all is well.  By the way, you should set this as your accepted answer if you feel that it adequately addresses your question, which it sounds like is the case.